# Running OpenCart in my mobile application

Tags: android, ios, api, opencart

I'd like to know if it's a way to write a mobile application which can purchase products through `OpenCart` website. Here are two possible methods I can think of. Please suggest which one is better or if there is another better way:

1. **OMF** - OpenCart mobile framework. I guest it's just a theme for the open cart website. Is it possible to run this inside `PhoneGap` ?
2. OpenCart Restful API. We can build the native UI in mobile application. But if there are any limitations?

I'll appreciate if anybody who have experience to build the open cart website for the mobile application advise. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have u got any extensions?

Comment: I ll suggest second one. Opencart provide REST API for mobile app http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18650 , Actually its come along with lot of features ( Just click that link & see their REST API features). This API is customizable, so there is no limitations, you can update whatever you want. You need further help visit Contus M Comm - Opencart

Comment: Yeah. Opencart REST API is fully customizable. It is the best choice if you ask me. http://www.contus.com/opencart-mobile-app.php

Comment: I'm suggest to going for OpenCart. Opt for the REST Api for best results. Also you can also try a readymade solution that is up for grabs. Appthitect's solution is completely customizable and can be molded anyway you want.   http://www.apphitect.ae/mobile-commerce-app.php

Answer (score 2):

I shall answer because I was working on somewhat similar project before. Your suggested solutions first.

1] Using phonegap you develop hybrid mobile apps which run on webview on respected mobile platforms. And I don't recommend this method because what it does is renders the exact website DOM in mobile's webview and it will get rejected by **Apple** since they won't allow this due to native design guidelines consistency. So, unless you are only targeting **Android** users, forget this option.

2] Building native mobile app is preferable. However I should give you a heads-up that **Opencart** has prewritten **APIs** for Orders, customers, shipping, vouchers etc but not for products. You will have to manually write it.

I can't figure out what limitations you are referring. Obviously, in a mobile app the desktop version extensions won't work. the requirement mentioned in the first line of question can certainly be meet using API with native development.